# Using beautifulsoup to download video

Tags: python, html, video, beautifulsoup

Recently i learned beautifulsoup and am trying to download files from webpages. 
Now i am trying to download the video from this webpage [ozee](http://www.ozee.com/shows/mirakkel-akkel-challenger-season-9/video/mirakkel-akkel-challenger-season-9-episode-76-may-28-2016-full-episode.html).
Using IDM I can download video with .TS extension, But "`soup`" object has no such link. Also using inspect element i can find the player window `div class "video-player"`, but also there is no link.
Is this video link even downloadable?
I'm beyond the limit of my Python abilities, any help will be appreciable.

Comment: What exactly do you want to download?

Comment: the video off-course

Comment: There are multiple links to videos on the page, you want just the one in the id=container?

Comment: the main video that starts playing in the player window in the center of the webpage.

Comment: yes the one with <div class="video-player ">
<div id="container"....